# EF4 code-first - insanely nested UNION ALL and duplicated joins?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have a class with quite a few includes in its 'default get method', like this:

```
_dbContext.Users
    .Include(c => c.PublicContact)
    .Include(c => c.PrivateContact)
    .Include(c => c.Product)
    .Include(c => c.Languages)
    .Include(c => c.Categories)
    .Include(c => c.Memberships)
    .Include(c => c.SearchWords)
    .Include(c => c.Referals)
    .Include(c => c.Files)
    .Include(c => c.Articles);
```

Users inherit from BaseEntity that looks like this:

```
public class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
    public BaseEntity()
    {
        DateTime createdTime = DateTime.Now;
        Created = createdTime;
        Modified = createdTime;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
}
```

When query against that, trying to find a specific user it takes several seconds (actually almost a whole minute) - so i added a profiler and almost fell down the chair observing the actual SQL generated...

Its a loooooooong SQL - i tried pasting it into gmail to email a friend, but gmail (in chrome) lagged me out. Needless to say, i won't be pasting it all here, just give you a jist of what's wrong.

It starts out like this:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 int = 1,
        @p__linq__1 int = 153

SELECT 
[UnionAll6].[C2] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll6].[C3] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll6].[C4] AS [C3],
...
[UnionAll6].[C121] AS [C121], 
[UnionAll6].[C122] AS [C122], 
[UnionAll6].[C123] AS [C123]
FROM  (SELECT 
        [UnionAll5].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [UnionAll5].[C2] AS [C2], 
        [UnionAll5].[C3] AS [C3],
```

As you can see, it selects from 'UnionAll6' which is because it nests these insane selects in 6 (SIX!) levels.

When i look into the inner nesting (UnionAll1) i find that it's actually nested even deeper - this time it selects from something called [Limit1], [Limit2], etc. where it does selecting against fields with the right names, like this '[Limit1].[EmailAddress] AS [EmailAddress]'. At this level (along with selecting Limit1.EmailAddress) i also find this:

```
CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C2], 
CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C3], 
CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4],
```

All this selecting is actually nested *again* this time from something like this:

```
(SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[EmailAddress] AS [EmailAddress], 
    [Extent1].[LongDescription] AS [LongDescription], 
    [Extent1].[Modified] AS [Modified],
```

This level seems to be the last one, and some heavy left outer join is performed (actually some of it is against an extra nested select). This is then UNION ALL with some other crap, looking excatly the same.

I have some many-to-many relations - they are defined like this in the configuration:

```
public class UsersConfiguration : EntityBaseConfiguration<Users>
{
    public UsersConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(c => c.Languages).WithMany();
        HasMany(c => c.Categories).WithMany();
    }
}

public class EntityBaseConfiguration<T> : EntityConfiguration<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public EntityBaseConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        Property(e => e.Id).IsIdentity();
        Property(e => e.Timestamp).IsConcurrencyToken()
            .IsRequired()
            .HasStoreType("timestamp")
            .StoreGeneratedPattern = StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed;
        Property(e => e.Created)
            .StoreGeneratedPattern = StoreGeneratedPattern.None;
        Property(e => e.Modified)
            .StoreGeneratedPattern = StoreGeneratedPattern.None;
    }
}
```

I'm running against the CTP 4 'v4.0.30319' and i want to upgraded, but doing so breaks a lot of stuff - my configuration doesn't work since a lot has been changed it seems. I would rewrite the whole stuff by upgrading if that solves this insane nesting problem, but i don't see how it would?

Comment: Show the whole mapping of the User entity and also mention if there is any inheritance involved.

Comment: Ok, i think i got it all now :)

Comment: Are all your entities derived from `BaseEntity`? Just for test try to remove this inheritance. It is possible that EF thinks about your mapping as one big TPC inheritance structure which would explain those unions.

Comment: You are violating your software license by continuing to use the CTP version long after the release version has been issued.  You only have a license for a CTP as long as it's still in beta.  You certainly don't have a "go-live" license for it.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: All entities derive from BaseEntity, yes. I am using TPC but even though i can see from blog posts that generates unions and nesting, i still don't understand why. TBT might be the way to go?

Comment: @Mystere Man: You got a point there, I promise i won't go live with it :) but i'd just rather wait with the upgrade till it's out of CTP/beta?

Comment: It is out of CTP more than four months.

Comment: Right. I'm upgrading now. So you think i should break away from TPC and try TPT instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i decided to not inherit from a base and instead implement an interface with the same properties my base had. This makes me break DRY since i'll need to re-implement all the same properties on all my entities. I can keep inheritance on the configurations though, so it's not all bad.

The generated SQL looks better now.